# how can website javascript code using same input data compute a different result depending on visitor?

Tags: javascript

The javascript code snippet below is on a website. Recently I've observed the code can produce different results for a visitor on the website than I obtain from my computer using the exact same data that the visitor input to the website. This seems to be visitor dependent (some visitors are fine). I've tried several computers/operating systems in my office, and they all produce the same (correct) results as each other, derived from the visitor's input data in question.

Part of the results (not shown below) provided by the website is a plot of the user's entered data, which I observe is always correct, so I know the visitor's input data they entered into the website (from which the javascript computation uses to compute a result) are interpreted correctly by their machine (I can see the plot the user receives (generated by auto-PDF email), and the same data entered in my computer produces the exact same plot for the entered data; just the results derived from this data are different).

In one case I analyzed, the visitor's incorrect data, mysteriously, was always a factor of 1.3 lower than the correct result. It doesn't seem like a rounding error or difference in 32b vs 64b OS.

Any ideas what could be causing such a thing? Is the code below not robust for all versions of javascript, or could different javascript versions product different results (seems hard to believe, but I'm using some fancy math below, maybe one of the mat functions is antiquated). Unfortunately I don't have access to a machine producing incorrect data to troubleshoot. I also don't know anything about the machine/OS/platform used by visitors (could be anything). Any ideas appreciated. I'm not that experienced with javascript (it could be something obvious below).

Thanks in advance.

```
function calculate(){
    var fc=document.abcform.CF.value*1;
    var of = new Array(20);
    var pn = new Array(20);
    var pj = new Array(19);
    var cbox = new Array(20);
    var alpha;
    var con;
    var segment;
    var subttl=0;
     of[0]=document.abcform.OS1.value*1; pn[0]=document.abcform.abc1.value*1;
     of[1]=document.abcform.OS2.value*1;  pn[1]=document.abcform.abc2.value*1;
     of[2]=document.abcform.OS3.value*1;  pn[2]=document.abcform.abc3.value*1;
     of[3]=document.abcform.OS4.value*1;  pn[3]=document.abcform.abc4.value*1;
     of[4]=document.abcform.OS5.value*1;  pn[4]=document.abcform.abc5.value*1;
     of[5]=document.abcform.OS6.value*1;  pn[5]=document.abcform.abc6.value*1;
     of[6]=document.abcform.OS7.value*1;  pn[6]=document.abcform.abc7.value*1;
     of[7]=document.abcform.OS8.value*1;  pn[7]=document.abcform.abc8.value*1;
     of[8]=document.abcform.OS9.value*1;  pn[8]=document.abcform.abc9.value*1;
     of[9]=document.abcform.OS10.value*1;  pn[9]=document.abcform.abc10.value*1;
     of[10]=document.abcform.OS11.value*1;  pn[10]=document.abcform.abc11.value*1;
     of[11]=document.abcform.OS12.value*1;  pn[11]=document.abcform.abc12.value*1;
     of[12]=document.abcform.OS13.value*1;  pn[12]=document.abcform.abc13.value*1;
     of[13]=document.abcform.OS14.value*1;  pn[13]=document.abcform.abc14.value*1;
     of[14]=document.abcform.OS15.value*1;  pn[14]=document.abcform.abc15.value*1;
     of[15]=document.abcform.OS16.value*1;  pn[15]=document.abcform.abc16.value*1;
     of[16]=document.abcform.OS17.value*1;  pn[16]=document.abcform.abc17.value*1;
     of[17]=document.abcform.OS18.value*1;  pn[17]=document.abcform.abc18.value*1;
     of[18]=document.abcform.OS19.value*1;  pn[18]=document.abcform.abc19.value*1;
     of[19]=document.abcform.OS20.value*1;  pn[19]=document.abcform.abc20.value*1;  

      cbox[0]=document.abcform.c1.checked; cbox[1]=document.abcform.c2.checked; cbox[2]=document.abcform.c3.checked;
      cbox[3]=document.abcform.c4.checked; cbox[4]=document.abcform.c5.checked; cbox[5]=document.abcform.c6.checked;
      cbox[6]=document.abcform.c7.checked; cbox[7]=document.abcform.c8.checked; cbox[8]=document.abcform.c9.checked;
      cbox[9]=document.abcform.c10.checked; cbox[10]=document.abcform.c11.checked; cbox[11]=document.abcform.c12.checked;
      cbox[12]=document.abcform.c13.checked; cbox[13]=document.abcform.c14.checked; cbox[14]=document.abcform.c15.checked;
      cbox[15]=document.abcform.c16.checked; cbox[16]=document.abcform.c17.checked; cbox[17]=document.abcform.c18.checked;
      cbox[18]=document.abcform.c19.checked; cbox[19]=document.abcform.c20.checked; 

    for (var i = 0; i <= 18; i++) { pj[i] = '' }
    for (var j = 1; j <= 19; j++){
        if (j == 1 || cbox[j]) {
            alpha = (pn[j-1] - pn[j])/(10*(Math.LOG10E*Math.log(of[j]/of[j-1])));
            con = (Math.pow(of[j-1],alpha))*(Math.pow(10,0.1*pn[j-1]));
            if ((alpha <= (1 + 1e-14)) && (alpha >= (1 - 1e-14))) { 
                segment = con*Math.log(of[j]/of[j-1]); }
                else { segment = (con/(1-alpha))*(Math.pow(of[j],1-alpha)-Math.pow(of[j-1],1-alpha)); }
            pj[j-1] = round(1E12*(Math.sqrt(2*segment))/(2*Math.PI*fc));
            subttl = subttl + Math.pow(pj[j-1],2);
        }   else {break;}
    }
    document.abcform.pj1.value=pj[0]; document.abcform.pj2.value=pj[1]; document.abcform.pj3.value=pj[2];
    document.abcform.pj4.value=pj[3]; document.abcform.pj5.value=pj[4]; document.abcform.pj6.value=pj[5];
    document.abcform.pj7.value=pj[6]; document.abcform.pj8.value=pj[7]; document.abcform.pj9.value=pj[8];
    document.abcform.pj10.value=pj[9]; document.abcform.pj11.value=pj[10]; document.abcform.pj12.value=pj[11];
    document.abcform.pj13.value=pj[12]; document.abcform.pj14.value=pj[13]; document.abcform.pj15.value=pj[14];
    document.abcform.pj16.value=pj[15]; document.abcform.pj17.value=pj[16]; document.abcform.pj18.value=pj[17];
    document.abcform.pj19.value=pj[18];
    document.abcform.tj.value=round(Math.sqrt(subttl));
    }

function round(x) { return Math.round(x*100000)/100000; }
```

Comment: You could dramatically shorten that code by using simple loops to populate the arrays and to put the result values back into the form. Won't fix your problem, but it'll make some adorable kittens really happy.

Comment: @Pointy, actually some cat might consider reading actual code in question, instead of those "NO LOOPS! NO LOOPS" protest signs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging, it turns out this is related to a loss of precision by converting to scientific notation in code not shown above. Thus, it's a non-javascript issue (e.g. user error). Thanks for all of the insight above though.

Answer (score 0):

> Doesn't seem like a rounding error or
>   difference in 32b vs 64b OS.

Why not... this is exactly what it seems like.  Maybe even a 16bit machine for that matter.  You are doing lots of crazy floating point operations -- they typically perform lots of truncation and rounding.

---

Option two:  The `log` or `pow` or `sqrt` functions are implemented differently on different browsers.  Solution -- implement your own and see if you get the same "different" results.

Comment: JavaScript floating point values are always IEEE 794 64-bit quantities, regardless of underlying hardware.

Comment: For the visitor input data in question, I tried the code using both 32b and 64b machines the output results from the code above matches exactly (at least to the formatted 5 decimal places).

Comment: @Pointy : I was not able to find anything which confirmed your point, but I believe you.  What about the Math.* functions -- is there a stated common algorithm?

Comment: @Hogan if you're trying to fall asleep you can find it in the [JavaScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf) - look for the part towards the beginning about the "Number" type.  I think that all the compliant math libraries are at least *supposed* to work. Since the nature of these mystery visitors is apparently unknown, you might be right - maybe they're using WebTV :-)

Comment: Well, I can't test for all browsers, past and future. If it is a browser-specific implementation of a math function, is it conceivable I could just specify the webpage "works" for browsers x, y, and z, including versions of each (which I can verify on my computer produces valid results), and be sure that all visitors will get the same results?

Comment: @ggkmath : just grab some infinite precision javascript library -- or a "common" math implementation.

Comment: @Hogan: Not sure what you mean, can you explain?

Comment: @ggkmath : Yeah.  For example include this file in your page (http://jsfromhell.com/classes/bignumber) and then do your math using the BigNumber object.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely sounds like rounding errors to me, and it doesn't matter what the underlying elements are (64 bit, 32 bit, implementations of pow, etc).

Consider:

```
alpha = (pn[j-1] - pn[j])/(10*(Math.LOG10E*Math.log(of[j]/of[j-1])));
(Math.pow(of[j-1],alpha))*(Math.pow(10,0.1*pn[j-1]))
```

That right there can have different results, since it's all floating math. You'll have to either use ints, or something like [BigNumber](http://jsfromhell.com/classes/bignumber).

Answer (score 0):

In cases like that printf debugging is sometimes helpful - print out all the intermediate values (like alpha) for all the iterations and then compare the outputs to see where they are different. Gives you a starting point.

Comment: I think this only works if I'm able to reproduce the problem. However, I can't seem to duplicate the incorrect results. Incidently, I used Firefox and Firebug to step through the code line by line and all computations are correct (I have a "golden" Matlab routine I use so I know what the answer should be), using the visitor's input data that lead them to the wrong result.

Comment: Are any of the intermediate results especially large or small? Extreme values are always a good candidate to throw things off

Comment: One other thing: your round method scales a number up by factor 10^5 - maybe toPrecision() is a better option

Comment: Thanks Chris, I stepped through some problem input data, and the smallest number during the computation was 8e-13. There was a step that required LOG base 10 of 10 = 1 (although I wouldn't expect that to be an issue). I wouldn't see where a rounding error could occur, unless someone's using less than 32bit system (wouldn't think that'd be possible though).